# Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I include the latest version of jQuery from the jquery.com site on my page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

then line 3 of the following code (pscript.js):

```
function init() {
    $("textbox").focus();
    $("textbox").addEventListener("keyup", _keytext, false); // line 3
    $("textbox").addEventListener("blur", _save, false);
    ...
```

produces the following error:

> pscript.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener'

I confirmed that this error goes away if the jquery script is not included. What am I doing wrong? How do I include jquery without the error?

Comment: Can we see the first few lines of `pscript.js`?

Comment: Images are next to worthless when it comes to code. Next time, please use proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem was that I had defined `$` function like this

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Now since jQuery has its own definition of `$`, my definition was getting overridden, and hence the unexpected error.

Answer (score 12):

Try `each` to access each node directly:

```
$("textbox").each(function(){
    this.addEventListener("keyup",_keytext,false);
});
```

or use a jQuery event handler attachment method:

```
$("textbox").bind("keyup",_keytext);
```

By default, [`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) is defined by jQuery to return a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), a node collection (with jQuery methods), rather than a single node. As such, the return value has no `addEventListener` method. [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (and [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) are used with jQuery, rather than `addEventListener`.

If you define your own `$` (or use another library that does so), you can revert the definition of `$` so that [jQuery will coexist with other libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) by calling [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Alternatively, include the other library or define `$` after including jQuery, so jQuery's definition will be overwritten.

Comment: But why don't I see this error if the jquery file is not included?

Comment: $("selector") is used by at least a couple libraries.  Your code (excluding jquery) can probably handle $("textbox") as a single node.  Are you using other libraries or toolkits besides jQuery?

Comment: you don't see the error but your code will not work either... if you leave jquery out, all your jquery code should error... it would probably say  something like $ is undefined  (because your code can't find the $ object which is an alias for jQuery)

Comment: Got it. I had actually defined $ to return id earlier and jquery file overrode it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In order to grab your element, you need to provide the selector `#textarea` otherwise, jQuery will try to select all elements with the textarea tag.

Comment: Also, `input` tags are self-closing, `</input>` can sometimes give you trouble in IE.